# extend larasap/fb post method

Tags: laravel, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to extend the functionality of a method from this package:
https://github.com/toolkito/laravel-social-auto-posting

Because the usage from mine controller is so simple, and others package makes a big mess even for basic operation like the one I need to achieve!

Goal: -posting text over a fb page with some tags of users that have allready puted a like to the same page.

So I Start from this call:

```
SendTo::Facebook(
 ‘link’,
 [
 ‘link’ => ‘https://github.com/toolkito/laravel-social-auto-posting',
 ‘message’ => ‘Laravel social auto posting’
 ]
);
```

If I simply cut the link part, the message part can be my text of the post, and all works easy.
If I try to add user's tag on the 'message' part with the notation:

```
@[userId]
```

thats not works and the tag part is cutted and only the text is showed:
If I send `'text'=>'some text @[mineuserid] more text''`
only

> 'some text more text'

is showed on the wall.

So I move to copy and extend the methods.
If I well understand from fb documentation I can tags user with the field `tags` but needs to be specified even the field `places` (in that case if I well understand my page's id)

So I start to explore into package, and trying to mods over sends link of the package:

```
public static function Facebook($type, $data)
    {
        switch ($type) {
            case 'link':
                $message = isset($data['message']) ? $data['message'] : '';
                $result = FacebookApi::sendLink($data['link'], $data['message']);
                break;

            case 'postolo':
                $message = isset($data['message']) ? $data['message'] :'';
                $tags =isset($data['tags']) ? $data['tags'] : '';
                $places =isset($data['places']) ? $data['places'] : '';

                $result = FacebookApi::sendPostolo( $message, $tags,$places);
                break;
```

Mine part is "postolo"

Then I found sendLink:

```
public static function sendLink($link, $message = '')
    {
        self::initialize();
        $data = compact('link', 'message');
        try {
            $response = self::$fb->post('/me/feed', $data, self::$page_access_token);
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            throw new \Exception('Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage());
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            throw new \Exception('Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage());
        }
        $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

        return $graphNode['id'];
    }
```

If I foolishly copy this and adapts it to my needs is something like:

```
 public static function sendPostolo($link, $message = '',$tags='',$places='')
    {
        self::initialize();
        $data = compact( 'tags','message','places');
        try {
            $response = self::$fb->post('/me/feed', $data, self::$page_access_token);
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            throw new \Exception('Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage());
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            throw new \Exception('Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage());
        }
        $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

        return $graphNode['id'];
    }
```

But at the end the method $fb->post() not works as espect to me, and just publishs the first data of my array  $data = compact( 'tags','message','places'); so in that case 'tags' and not as tags but predictably as plain text...

this is post() on fb package:

```
 public function post($endpoint, array $params = [], $accessToken = null, $eTag = null, $graphVersion = null)
    {
        return $this->sendRequest(
            'POST',
            $endpoint,
            $params,
            $accessToken,
            $eTag,
            $graphVersion
        );
    }
```

Comment: Your declared “goal” sounds spammy to begin with. Why would you want to tag users in these page posts, and what is the connection to them liking the page? Pretty sure you won’t get that kind of “auto posting” through app review in the first place.

Comment: from what i read from fb docs thats permitted... and i dont want spam anything, its for students allready subscribed in that page...

Comment: So _why_ do you want to tag them in these posts, what’s the purpose of that? Assuming they are already following your page, they would get to see the posts you make on that page in their newsfeed. Why the need for additional tagging?

Comment: because in fact the post is about a story composed by who will be tagged

Comment: So what does your `$data` content finally look like? Not sure `compact` is the best way to assemble that to begin with.

Comment: you point me in the right direction, data was not properly formatted, now it works!!! the only problem is that I see the post on the page...but not others user! why?

Comment: Because your app is still in development mode, so all content created through it is only visible to people with a role in the app. You need to set it “live”/public in the app dashboard. But then you will also have to submit it for review first, otherwise you won’t be able to grant the necessary permissions to the app in the first place.

Comment: thanks a lot you save me a lot of time!